# Is it impossible to have ListView inside SingleChildScrollView?

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

Is it impossible to have `ListView` inside `SingleChildScrollView`? We trying to create three button which work like radio group button. We have found the solution from [Flutter : Custom Radio Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50060276/flutter-custom-radio-button)
.

But in our case, it is wrapped by `SingleChildScrollView`.

```
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        Localization.of(context).priority,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                      ),
                      ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: sampleData.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return InkWell(
                            child: RadioItem(
                              sampleData[index],
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ]))
```

**Error**

```
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderShrinkWrappingViewport#4d85f relayoutBoundary=up27 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
RenderObject: RenderShrinkWrappingViewport#4d85f relayoutBoundary=up27 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
    needs compositing
    parentData: <none> (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
    size: MISSING
    axisDirection: down
    crossAxisDirection: right
    offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#fa7e6(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: null, ScrollableState, AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics -> ClampingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#d2e68, ScrollDirection.idle)
    child 0: RenderSliverPadding#37bf3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
        parentData: layoutOffset=0.0
        constraints: MISSING
        geometry: null
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero
        textDirection: ltr
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Surround you `ListView` with `Expanded` widget.

You can't have a scrollable widget inside another scrollable widget without setting a proper height for the inner one.

Or use `ConstrainedBox`

[image: sample]

Comment: Instead of showing code image, you should post code.

Comment: @Volleyball it is just the outline for the OP to proceed. No changes in OP's code is needed except the wrapper shown. This view shows the changes required rather than posting and completed code and finding what needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Inside of ListView.builder use

ListView.builder(
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
..........
)

Answer (score 0):

ListView.builder(physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), shrinkWrap: true, ),
OtherWise ListView.bulider wrap to Sizedbox and do fix Height and width

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).