# pageview inside Singlechildscrollview

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to put a pageview in a singlechildscrollview returned by a dragablescrollablesheet so that it begins from the half of the screen, can scroll from the bottom to the top of the screen by the singlechildscrollview and also scroll horizontally by the pageview. Here is the code:

```
DraggableScrollableSheet(
        initialChildSize: 0.4,
          minChildSize: 0.399,
          builder: (context,scrollcontroller) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: scrollcontroller,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: PageView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            children:[
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(80.0),
                                        topRight: Radius.circular(80.0),
                                      ),
                                      color: Colors.red
                                  ),
                                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                                  width:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(80.0),
                                        topRight: Radius.circular(80.0),
                                      ),
                                      color: Colors.deepOrange
                                  ),
                                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                                  width:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(80.0),
                                        topRight: Radius.circular(80.0),
                                      ),
                                      color: Colors.black
                                  ),
                                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                                  width:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                ),
                          ]
                          )
            );
        }
      )
```

but this error occures:

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown during performLayout():
The method 'toStringAsFixed' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: toStringAsFixed(1)

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PageView file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:97:26
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      ViewportOffset.debugFillDescription (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport_offset.dart:248:39)
#2      ScrollPosition.debugFillDescription (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart:896:11)
#3      ScrollPositionWithSingleContext.debugFillDescription (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position_with_single_context.dart:261:11)
#4      ViewportOffset.toString (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport_offset.dart:233:5)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderPointerListener#bea84 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: MISSING
...  behavior: deferToChild
...  listeners: signal
RenderObject: RenderPointerListener#bea84 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: MISSING
  behavior: deferToChild
  listeners: signal
...  child: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#081a5 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: <none> (can use size)
...    constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...    size: MISSING
...    gestures: <none>
...    child: RenderPointerListener#489ba relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: <none> (can use size)
...      constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...      size: MISSING
...      behavior: opaque
...      listeners: down
...      child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#21d33 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...        parentData: <none> (can use size)
...        constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...        size: MISSING
...        child: RenderIgnorePointer#10f37 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...          parentData: <none> (can use size)
...          constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...          size: MISSING
...          ignoring: false
...          ignoringSemantics: false
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#bea84 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PageView file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:97:26
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderScrollSemantics#99f96 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PageView file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:97:26
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#7030a relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PageView file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:97:26
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#adaca relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PageView file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:97:26
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#40087 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SingleChildScrollView file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:94:24
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderSingleChildViewport#15c06 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SingleChildScrollView file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:94:24
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#004d6 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SingleChildScrollView file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:94:24
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#601ea NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SingleChildScrollView file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:94:24
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#a0a1e NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SingleChildScrollView file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:94:24
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#bd3e8 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SingleChildScrollView file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:94:24
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#065b1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SingleChildScrollView file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:94:24
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderScrollSemantics#0a2c3 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SingleChildScrollView file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:94:24
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#b15d6 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SingleChildScrollView file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:94:24
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#6f5f2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SingleChildScrollView file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:94:24
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#6449d NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  DraggableScrollableSheet file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:89:11
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFractionallySizedOverflowBox#727c4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  DraggableScrollableSheet file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:89:11
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderConstrainedBox#58dfa relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  DraggableScrollableSheet file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:89:11
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderLayoutBuilder#31659 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Stack file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:29:16
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderStack#ad16a relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SafeArea file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:28:12
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#20d61 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:24:12
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderLayoutBuilder#ac8ab relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:24:12
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by Flutter framework =====================================================
The method 'toStringAsFixed' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: toStringAsFixed(1)
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during paint():
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#6449d NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  DraggableScrollableSheet file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:89:11
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderBox.size (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1785:12)
#3      RenderBox.paintBounds (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:41)
#4      PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:139:59)
#5      PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:100:5)
#6      PaintingContext._compositeChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:206:7)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderFractionallySizedOverflowBox#727c4
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=771.4)
...  size: MISSING
...  alignment: bottomCenter
...  textDirection: ltr
...  widthFactor: pass-through
...  heightFactor: 0.4
RenderObject: RenderFractionallySizedOverflowBox#727c4
  needs compositing
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=771.4)
  size: MISSING
  alignment: bottomCenter
  textDirection: ltr
  widthFactor: pass-through
  heightFactor: 0.4
...  child: RenderRepaintBoundary#6449d NEEDS-PAINT
...    needs compositing
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
...    constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=308.6)
...    layer: OffsetLayer#d683d DETACHED
...      engine layer: Null#007db
...      offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...    size: MISSING
...    metrics: 0.0% useful (1 bad vs 0 good)
...    diagnosis: insufficient data to draw conclusion (less than five repaints)
...    child: RenderCustomPaint#6f5f2 NEEDS-PAINT
...      needs compositing
...      parentData: <none> (can use size)
...      constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=308.6)
...      size: MISSING
...      child: RenderRepaintBoundary#b15d6 NEEDS-PAINT
...        needs compositing
...        parentData: <none> (can use size)
...        constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=308.6)
...        size: MISSING
...        usefulness ratio: no metrics collected yet (never painted)
...        child: _RenderScrollSemantics#0a2c3 NEEDS-PAINT
...          needs compositing
...          parentData: <none> (can use size)
...          constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=308.6)
...          semantic boundary
...          size: MISSING
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during paint():
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#6449d NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  DraggableScrollableSheet file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:89:11
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderBox.size (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1785:12)
#3      RenderBox.paintBounds (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:41)
#4      PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:139:59)
#5      PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:100:5)
#6      PaintingContext._compositeChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:206:7)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderFractionallySizedOverflowBox#727c4
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=771.4)
...  size: MISSING
...  alignment: bottomCenter
...  textDirection: ltr
...  widthFactor: pass-through
...  heightFactor: 0.4
RenderObject: RenderFractionallySizedOverflowBox#727c4
  needs compositing
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=771.4)
  size: MISSING
  alignment: bottomCenter
  textDirection: ltr
  widthFactor: pass-through
  heightFactor: 0.4
...  child: RenderRepaintBoundary#6449d NEEDS-PAINT
...    needs compositing
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
...    constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=308.6)
...    layer: OffsetLayer#d683d DETACHED
...      engine layer: Null#007db
...      offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...    size: MISSING
...    metrics: 0.0% useful (2 bad vs 0 good)
...    diagnosis: insufficient data to draw conclusion (less than five repaints)
...    child: RenderCustomPaint#6f5f2 NEEDS-PAINT
...      needs compositing
...      parentData: <none> (can use size)
...      constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=308.6)
...      size: MISSING
...      child: RenderRepaintBoundary#b15d6 NEEDS-PAINT
...        needs compositing
...        parentData: <none> (can use size)

...        constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=308.6)
...        size: MISSING
...        usefulness ratio: no metrics collected yet (never painted)
...        child: _RenderScrollSemantics#0a2c3 NEEDS-PAINT
...          needs compositing
...          parentData: <none> (can use size)
...          constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=308.6)
...          semantic boundary
...          size: MISSING
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#6449d NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  DraggableScrollableSheet file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:89:11
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during paint():
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#6449d NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  DraggableScrollableSheet file:///C:/Users/georg/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/UI/welcome.dart:89:11
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderBox.size (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1785:12)
#3      RenderBox.paintBounds (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:41)
#4      PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:139:59)
#5      PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:100:5)
#6      PaintingContext._compositeChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:206:7)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderFractionallySizedOverflowBox#727c4
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=771.4)
...  size: MISSING
...  alignment: bottomCenter
...  textDirection: ltr
...  widthFactor: pass-through
...  heightFactor: 0.4
RenderObject: RenderFractionallySizedOverflowBox#727c4
  needs compositing
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=771.4)
  size: MISSING
  alignment: bottomCenter
  textDirection: ltr
  widthFactor: pass-through
  heightFactor: 0.4
...  child: RenderRepaintBoundary#6449d NEEDS-PAINT
...    needs compositing
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
...    constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=308.6)
...    layer: OffsetLayer#d683d DETACHED
...      engine layer: Null#007db
...      offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...    size: MISSING
...    metrics: 0.0% useful (4 bad vs 0 good)
...    diagnosis: insufficient data to draw conclusion (less than five repaints)
...    child: RenderCustomPaint#6f5f2 NEEDS-PAINT
...      needs compositing
...      parentData: <none> (can use size)
...      constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=308.6)
...      size: MISSING
...      child: RenderRepaintBoundary#b15d6 NEEDS-PAINT
...        needs compositing
...        parentData: <none> (can use size)
...        constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=308.6)
...        size: MISSING
...        usefulness ratio: no metrics collected yet (never painted)
...        child: _RenderScrollSemantics#0a2c3 NEEDS-PAINT
...          needs compositing
...          parentData: <none> (can use size)
...          constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=308.6)
...          semantic boundary
...          size: MISSING
===========================================================
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI50Y.png)

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57893006/

Comment: Wrap your pageView with `Expanded` widget or `ConstrainedBox` widget.

Comment: I didn't get any exception from this code..

Comment: Flutter 1.25.0-8.3.pre • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5d36f2e7f5 (3 weeks ago) • 2021-01-14 15:57:49 -0800
Engine • revision 7a8f8ca02c
Tools • Dart 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-133.7.beta)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all it worked for me just by wrapping the page view in a container with fixed hight