# How to create radio button with image in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to create RadioListTile like this in Flutter/Dart. I tried  but didn't get success.
When user select gender that selected button should display in white icon with grey background

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50060276/flutter-custom-radio-button

Comment: yes its working but I want do using Radio Button widget

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image]

You can try this approach:

```
int _value = 0;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => setState(() => _value = 0),
            child: Container(
              height: 56,
              width: 56,
              color: _value == 0 ? Colors.grey : Colors.transparent,
              child: Icon(Icons.call),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 4),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => setState(() => _value = 1),
            child: Container(
              height: 56,
              width: 56,
              color: _value == 1 ? Colors.grey : Colors.transparent,
              child: Icon(Icons.message),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, Its working but can we create it with radio button not @CopsOnRoad

Comment: Hi, there is no `RadioButton` widget in Flutter, did you mean simple `Radio` or `RadioListTile`?

Comment: Yes thats i mean @CopsOnRoad

Comment: The question you posted was using icon, so I posted the answer for the same, I've added a new answer which now uses `RadioListTile`.

Comment: i have used your approach, the problem is the UI state is not updating without hot reload, any idea please ?