# How change the visual of List of Radio button?

Tags: flutter

I have a bet game it is a list of game and user need to choose between 3 choices (only one choice) (1,N,2) so i use radio in flutter for do it.

1 - Here is the result i have now :

[image]

2 - Here is the result i want to have :

[image]

I need have the same radio 1 N 2 without using any images, i think it is possible to do it using clipoval perhaps with rounded borders. Here the selected radio is in RED in background so when i click on another radio it needs change the color of radio (red background and white color font if selected and white background and red color font if not selected)
And now here is my entire code for the grid :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
            import 'dart:convert';
            import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
            import 'dart:async';
            import 'package:flutter_app/menu_member.dart';
            import 'package:flutter_app/globals.dart' as globals;
            import 'package:flutter_app/grille_lotosport.dart';

        // Create

     a Form widget.
class Affiche_grille extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  String id;

  Affiche_grille({Key key, @required this.id}) : super(key: key);

  _Affiche_grille_State createState() {
    return _Affiche_grille_State();
  }
}

// Create a corresponding State class.
// This class holds data related to the form.

class _Affiche_grille_State extends State<Affiche_grille> {
  @override
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  List<String> radioValues = [];
  Future<List<Match>> grid;

  Future <List<Match>> Grille_display() async {
    // SERVER LOGIN API URL
    var url = 'https://www.easytrafic.fr/game_app/display_grid.php';

    // Store all data with Param Name.
    var data = {'id_grille': widget.id};

    // Starting Web API Call.
    var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(data),headers: {'content-type': 'application/json','accept': 'application/json','authorization': globals.token});

    // Getting Server response into variable.

    var jsondata = json.decode(response.body);

    List<Match> Matchs = [];

    for (var u in jsondata) {
      Match match = Match(u["equipe1"],u["equipe2"],u["type_prono"]);
      Matchs.add(match);
      radioValues.add("N");
    }
    return Matchs;
  }

  void initState() {
    grid = Grille_display();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('GRILLE LOTOSPORT'),
        ),
        drawer: new DrawerOnly(),
        body:
        Container(
          child:
            FutureBuilder(
              future: grid,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {

              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return new Center(
                    child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                default:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return new Center(
                      child: new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),);
                  }
                  else {
                    List<Match> values = snapshot.data;
                    return Form(
                        key: _formKey,
                        child: ListView(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            DataTable(
                              columnSpacing: 20,
                              columns: [
                                DataColumn(
                                  label: Text("Libelle Match"),
                                  numeric: false,
                                  tooltip: "",
                                ),
                                DataColumn(
                                  label: Text("1"),
                                  numeric: false,
                                  tooltip: "",
                                ),
                                DataColumn(
                                  label: Text("N"),
                                  numeric: false,
                                  tooltip: "",
                                ),
                                DataColumn(
                                  label: Text("2"),
                                  numeric: false,
                                  tooltip: "",
                                ),
                              ],
                              rows:
                              List.generate(values.length, (index) {
                                return DataRow(
                                    cells: [
                                      DataCell(
                                        Text(values[index].equipe1.toString() +
                                            " - " +
                                            values[index].equipe2.toString()),
                                      ),
                                      DataCell(
                                        Radio(
                                          value: "1",
                                          groupValue: radioValues[index],
                                          onChanged: (val) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              radioValues[index] = val;
                                            });
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      DataCell(
                                        Radio(
                                          value: "N",
                                          groupValue: radioValues[index],
                                          onChanged: (val) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              radioValues[index] = val;
                                            });
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      DataCell(
                                        Radio(
                                          value: "2",
                                          groupValue: radioValues[index],
                                          onChanged: (val) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              radioValues[index] = val;
                                            });
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ]
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                            ),
                            Center(
                              child: RaisedButton(
                                color: Colors.green,
                                textColor: Colors.white,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(9, 9, 9, 9),
                                child: Text('VALIDER VOTRE GRILLE'),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Valide_grille();
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                    );
                  };
              };
                },
            ),
        ),
    ),
    );
  }

  Future Valide_grille() async{
    // For CircularProgressIndicator.
    bool visible = false ;
    // Showing CircularProgressIndicator.
    setState(() {
      visible = true ;
    });

    // SERVER LOGIN API URL
    var url = 'https://www.easytrafic.fr/game_app/valide_grid.php';

    var concatenate='';

    radioValues.forEach((item){
      concatenate=concatenate+item;
    });

    var id_grille=widget.id;

    // Store all data with Param Name.
    var data = {'id_membre':globals.id_membre, 'id_grille':id_grille,'result':concatenate};

    var grille_encode=jsonEncode(data);

    // Starting Web API Call.
    var response = await http.post(url, body: grille_encode,headers: {'content-type': 'application/json','accept': 'application/json','authorization': globals.token});

    print(response.body);
    // Getting Server response into variable.
    Map <String,dynamic> map2 = json.decode(response.body);

    // If the Response Message is Matched.
    if(map2["status"] == 1)
    {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: new Text(map2["message"]),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: new Text("OK"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Affiche_Liste_grille()),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
      // Hiding the CircularProgressIndicator.
      setState(() {
        visible = false;
      });

    }else{
      // Hiding the CircularProgressIndicator.
      setState(() {
        visible = false;
      });

      // Showing Alert Dialog with Response JSON Message.
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: new Text(map2["message"]),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: new Text("OK"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
  }

class Match {

  final String equipe1;
  final String equipe2;
  final String typeprono;

  const Match(this.equipe1, this.equipe2, this.typeprono);

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter : Custom Radio Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50060276/flutter-custom-radio-button)

Comment: You can try using ToggleButton instead of Radio. 
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ToggleButtons-class.html

Comment: i need use a list of radio button because each game have 3 choices 1 N 2. So first line you need to choose between 1 N 2 and second line too. It is the difficulty and the difference with your example

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, i Don't understand why it works but it works now with allmy corrections. I Don't understand why when i put a setstate all elements are updated correctly, i put no code in the setstate but all is now updated, it is very strange