# How to fetch the value of selected CustomRadioButton on flutter form submit?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to fetch the value from the selected CustomRadioButton and want to pass those values through Providerso that by navigating to the homepage, those data can be seen.
How do I do that? Please provide me any suggestions!

Below is my code.

```
submit() async{
    _formKey.currentState.save();
    print(nameController.text);
    getCurrentLocation(context);
    print(latitudeData);

/*here I want to fetch that selected button's value*/
  }




void showDialogBox() {
    // flutter defined function
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: AlertDialog(
            insetPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 80, bottom: 80),
                actions: [
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                    width: 350,
//.........


//.........

Container(
                              width: 200,
                              child: CustomRadioButton(
                                customShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: 
                                BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                elevation: 0,
                                absoluteZeroSpacing: false,
                                unSelectedColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                                buttonLables: [
                                  'Male',
                                  'Female',
                                ],
                                buttonValues: [
                                  "MALE",
                                  "FEMALE",
                                ],
                                buttonTextStyle: ButtonTextStyle(
                                    textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 10)),
                                radioButtonValue: (value) {
                                  print(value);
                                },
                                width: 80,
                                height: 60,
                                enableShape: true,
                                selectedBorderColor: Colors.green,
                                unSelectedBorderColor: Color(0xFFD0D7EB),
                                selectedColor: Colors.green,
                              ),
                            ),
```

Please anybody help me!

Comment: Abhipsa, here you have an example of what you need to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50060276/flutter-custom-radio-button